# PC randomly logs off

Tags: windows-10, logoff, hp, random

My windows10 HP pc randomly logs off for no apparent reason. I have disabled all sleep settings and screensavers yet it still does it randomly without warning or any kind of error message, my ESET antivirus has picked up nothing so I thought is was a bad HDD. I switched to a new SSD but now its happening to it too. BIOS has not detected anything wrong so I have no idea why its happening. I am trying to figure out how to stop it from happening.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you really sure it logs you off? If you login, do you get a fresh windows, or does it actually resume where you left it? Screensaver can lock your computer, requiring a password to log on. How frequent does it happen? Can it happen while you are using the computer?

Comment: It resumes where i left off, my screensaver is disabled and it happens randomly even while im using it.

Comment: You could check if there's any related messages in the event viewer.

Comment: My friend who is more tech savy than I checked that when it was happening to my HDD but didnt find anyting.

Comment: I found some warnings and errors in admin event (kernel event tracing, VSS, windowsupdate client, client-licensing, disk, distributedCOM, Microsoft security client, service control manager)